# Removing same values in columns in some rows of a file in R

Tags: r

I have a file like this.

```
1  3
1  2
1  10
1  5
**5  5**
6  7
8  9
4  6
1  2 
**10 10**
......
```

The file contains thousands of rows. I wanted to know, how can I remove the rows which contains the same values in columns in R ( The row containing 5 5 and row containing 10 10 )? I know how to remove duplicate columns or duplicate rows, but how do I go about selectively removing them? Thanks. :)

Comment: `dat[dat[[1]]!=dat[[2]],]` should do it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this with indexing, example with small data frame:

```
myDf <- data.frame(a=c(3,5,8,6,9,4,3), b=c(3,3,5,8,9,6,4))
myDf <- myDf[myDf$a != myDf$b,]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider writing a helper function like this:

```
indicator <- function(indf) {
  rowSums(vapply(indf, function(x) x == indf[, 1], 
                 logical(nrow(indf)))) == ncol(indf)
}
```

Basically, the function compares each column in the `data.frame` with the first column of the `data.frame`, then, checks to see which `rowSums` are the same as the number of columns in the `data.frame`.

This basically creates a logical vector that can be used to subset your `data.frame`.

Example:

```
mydf <- data.frame(a=c(3,5,8,6,9,4,3), 
                   b=c(3,3,5,8,9,6,4),
                   c=c(3,4,5,6,9,7,2))

indicator(mydf)
# [1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE

mydf[!indicator(mydf), ]
#   a b c
# 2 5 3 4
# 3 8 5 5
# 4 6 8 6
# 6 4 6 7
# 7 3 4 2
```